# Read the first and last character of line in txt

Tags: php

I wanna take lines that start with capital and end with dot.

```
function isCapital($string) {
    return preg_match('/^\\s*[A-Z]/', $string) > 0;
}

foreach ($url as $file => $files) {
    $lines = file($files);
    foreach ($lines as $key => $line) {
        if (isCapital($line) && (substr($line, -1) == '.')) {
            print_r( $line);
        }
    }
}
```

But, it does not work, blank result. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `foreach($lines...` with this one below:

```
foreach ($lines as $key => $line) {
    if (preg_match('~^\s*[A-Z].*\.\s*$~', $line)) {
        print_r($line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems a bit off.  `\\s*` is looking for a literal backslash followed by any number of the letter `s`.  Remove one of the `\` and you should make progress.

Comment: Two backslashes is the proper escaping within PHP strings (both double and single quoted) leading to a single backslash; which is in turn what will reach libpcre.